# Android- I want to set the visibilty of a textView in a listview row on clicking the button in the same listrow

Tags: android, android-listview

---

[TextView1] [TextView2] [Button]

---

List row contains 2 TextView and 1 Button.

Initially [TextView2] visibility is set View.GONE.

1. Requirement is on clicking [Button] in a row the visibilty of  [TextView2] of that same row should be set to View.VISIBLE
2. and for next click on [Button] should set the visibilty of  [TextView2] as View.GONE. That is on clicking [Button] the visibility of the [TextView2] should be checked and it's current visibilty should be changed to its opposite visibility state
3. i.e. For each click on [Button] if [TextView2] is visible then make it invisible and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
    final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView textView2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (textView2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (textView2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);              

        }
    });
```

Comment: Change textView2.VISIBLE to textView2.getVisibility() and use constants like View.GONE and View.INVISIBLE instead of 0 and 1. It's confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 questions for you :
- is your activity a ListActivity ?
- what is your list adapter ? out-of-box or custom ?

--
Correction :

```
final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final TextView textView2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (textView2.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE) textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (textView2.getVisibility()== View.GONE) textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             

    }
});
```